# WordPress Gavity Forms (Authorized.net add-on) how to move labels above the fields

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

While all the labels in Gravity Forms are above the fields for some reason the Authorized.net add-on has them below the fields.  How can I move them up? Also the font slightly smaller and non-bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably too late, but you can try this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-enhancements/

It moves the labels before complexed fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had to edit the plugin's php file in order to move the labels but I will try the plugin to see if it allows me to move then that way.